# Link to File's path with spaces in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink, path, richtextbox

I have VS2010, C#. I use RichTextBox in a form.  I set the DectectUrls property to True. I set a LinkClicked event.

I would like open a file link like this: **file://C:\Documents and Settings...**  or **file://C:\Program Files (x86)...**

It doesn't works for path with spaces.

The source code:

```
rtbLog.SelectionFont = fnormal;
rtbLog.AppendText("\t. Open Path" + "file://" + PathAbsScript + "\n\n");


// DetectUrls set to true
// launch any http:// or mailto: links clicked in the body of the rich text box
private void rtbLog_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
   }
   catch (Exception) {}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should enclose the path with double quotes (`"file://c:\path with spaces\..."`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I use a replace (" ", "%20")

```
// http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/Vsexpressvb/thread/addc7b0e-e1fd-43f4-b19c-65a5d88f739c
var rutaScript = DatosDeEjecucion.PathAbsScript;
if (rutaScript.Contains(" ")) rutaScript = "file://" + Path.GetDirectoryName(DatosDeEjecucion.PathAbsScript).Replace(" ", "%20");
rtbLog.AppendText(". Abrir ubicación: " + rutaScript + "\n\n");
```

The code for LinkClicked event:

```
private void rtbLog_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
            try
            {
                var link = e.LinkText.Replace("%20", " ");
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(link);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using %20 (which some users may find "ugly" looking), you can use the UNICODE non-breaking space character (U+00A0). For example:

```
String fileName = "File name with spaces.txt";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

// Replace any ' ' characters with unicode non-breaking space characters:
richTextBox.AppendText("file://" + fi.FullName.Replace(' ', (char)160));
```

Then inside your link click handler for the rich text box, you'd do the following:

```
private void richTextBox_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // Replace any unicode non-break space characters with ' ' characters:
    string linkText = e.LinkText.Replace((char)160, ' ');

    // For some reason rich text boxes strip off the 
    // trailing ')' character for URL's which end in a 
    // ')' character, so if we had a '(' opening bracket
    // but no ')' closing bracket, we'll assume there was
    // meant to be one at the end and add it back on. This 
    // problem is commonly encountered with wikipedia links!

    if((linkText.IndexOf('(') > -1) && (linkText.IndexOf(')') == -1))
        linkText += ")";

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(linkText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have to put the path in quotes additionally to get it working. But then its fine... :-)

Comment: Mmmh. It seems that the solution of dyImcc is only working on Windows Vista or higher. On legacy Windows XP it does not work for me and I have to use the ugly spaces "%20" (no quotes needed here).

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose the path with double quotes, e.g.:

```
"file://c:\path with spaces\..."
```

To add a double quote to a string, you must use an escape sequence `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

go to that particular folder and give the permission to write or make it shared from properties of that folder.