# Link to file path with space in Richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am using richtextbox in winforms.
I have to show some links in the richtextbox which will be set readonly.
It works fine for the links with out spaces like

> \\efile\DSC_0618.JPG

But when the file has space like

> \\2527 threshold.png

it wont work and link will get broke due to space.

i have used the solution mentioned in this link [Link to File's path with spaces in RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157930/link-to-files-path-with-spaces-in-richtextbox)

But the problem is that escape sequence also get displayed in the Richtextbox according to that.

Is there any way i can make it as link without using escape sequence?

Comment: can you use an @ before the string to make a literal string?

Comment: Have tried that it wont work.The link will get break, when the space encounters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this link http://www.codeproject.com/cs/miscctrl/RichTextBoxLinks.asp which can help you insert a link of any text into a `RichTextBox`. There is a special note about how to fetch the `LinkText` and `Link Url` here which doesn't seem to be found in the original demo. Here I'll demonstrate the link info fetching in `LinkClicked` event handler:

```
//Insert link to test
richTextBoxEx1.InsertLink("StackOverFlow", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
//LickClicked event handler
private void richTextBoxEx1_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
        string[] s = e.LinkText.Split(new string[]{@"#http://"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (s.Length == 2)
        {
            s[1] = "http://" + s[1];
            MessageBox.Show("A link has been clicked.\nThe link text is '" + s[0] + "'\nThe link URL is '" + s[1] + "'");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(s[1]);//Try visiting the link.
        }
}
```

I think this is the most beautiful solution for you (and others who have the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like something basic, which has the effect of visually mimicking spaces in file names, simply replace the space characters (' ') with the UNICODE non-breaking space (U+00A0), and then in the link click handler do the reverse. See my answer to a similar question here for the sample code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19853473/2967903