# local URLs in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TextBox where I can send data to some RichTextBox. When I type something like `file:///FilePath1/FilePath2/FileName3.txt`, send to RichTextBox and click on the link (*LinkClicked Event*) it works and I can open the file but if some FilePath has spaces (for exemple `file:///File Path1/FilePath 2/FileName3.txt`) it doesn't works.

I tryed

```
string myString = myString.FileName;
myString = myString.Replace(" ", "%20");  // '%20' not accepted because it 
                                          //                changes the FileName
```

and

```
Uri myLink = new Uri(myString );
```

but it's still not working. Any sugestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link to file path with space in Richtextbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719021/link-to-file-path-with-space-in-richtextbox)

Comment: this is not easy at all, there is a custom RichTextBox which allows you to display link with arbitrary text in `codeproject` at here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox

Comment: @Chris the issue is the same but none of the answers worked for me

Comment: tried [Url Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)?

Comment: @Omribitan `var myLink = Uri.EscapeDataString(myString );` didn't work

Comment: @mafap you don't know how to modify the code to make it work for you.

Comment: @KingKing I was refering to the possible duplicate answers. I had seen this article in codeproject already, I was just looking for another way to do that.

Comment: sorry @KingKing can you explain how to use the solution shown in the article/duplicate question? It gives me some errors in `InsertLink` and other funtions.

Comment: @KingKing I imported the .DLL but it doesn't work :/

Comment: @mafap I've made a demo for you at here http://www.mediafire.com/?ts7l8jdnuhehi07 **It's very simple**. The point is the `e.LinkText` got in `LinkClicked` event handler contains both `actual link text` and `link url` separated by the character **#**

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for your help and time but I solved this using `myString = myString.Replace(" ", "%20");` and in `LinkClicked` event using a try-catch statement where catch calls a new Process to open my file.